# How to show something, once specific script is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, social-media

I have a small tool that has social media share buttons on it.
The API's for the buttons takes many seconds to load, the tab has a spinning icon and the buttons are visible but not usable. Which is obviously bad.

I am now using the small script below to load the API's after the page has loaded, which i want to keep.

```
<script>
// Load the share API's once the entire page is loaded.
    $(window).bind("load", function() {
       $.getScript('js/share.js', function() {});
    });
</script>
```

But I also want to hide the social media button div, until the APIs in the script have been loaded, how can i achieve this?

Comment: The second parameter of `$.getScript()` works as callback. Type some code inside!

Comment: This doesn't quite do it, I need to wait for the APIs to load, not just the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your div display none and then show it after script is loaded using the anonymous callback you already have setup.

HTML:

```
<div id="socialmedia" class="hide"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {
    $.getScript('js/share.js',
        function () {
            $('#socialmedia').removeClass('hide');
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: This isnt quite what I need. I need to remove the class once the API's have loaded not just the script.

Comment: So once you get the script does it automatically run to load whatever you need or do you need to call something for it to load? If there is a call to load this stuff after the you get the script perhaps that offers a callback?

Comment: There is a trigger, but Im not sure if there is a callback. I am using this: https://github.com/ritz078/socialShare.js

Comment: Yea it doesn't look like it does. You could try using jquery queue to make things run synchronously.